# List: How to tell if Letters in a list are in a Word?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, python-3.x

For example, if you had a list

```
C=''
B='apple'
A=['a','b','c','d','e']
```

How would you go about seeing if any letters in that list are in the word 'apple', showing the user what letters are in it, and showing a "-" for each letter not shown in the list. For example apple would be a---e. I thought it would be something like...

```
for item in A:
     if item in B:
          C+=item
     else:
          C+='-'
print(C)
```

But I can't figure it out. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you may actually want things the other way 'round.  Right now, you're looping over each letter in the list and asking if it's in the word-- do you actually want to loop over each letter in the word and ask if it's in the list?  (Your example is unfortunate, because both would result in `a---e`.)

Comment: Would there be a way to make it go through each letter in the word and comparing it to a list? That would make life a whole lot easier for me.

Answer (score 8):

```
>>> B = 'apple'
>>> A = ['a','b','c','d','e']
>>> print ''.join(c if c in B else '-' for c in A)
a---e
```

This is equivalent to this `for` loop:

```
>>> s = ''
>>> for c in A:
        if c in B:
            s += c
        else:
            s += '-'


>>> print s
a---e
```

Comment: Would there be a way to make it go through each letter in the word and comparing it to a list? That would make life a whole lot easier for me.

Comment: @Bob sure, just switch the `A` with `B` eg. `print ''.join(c if c in A else '-' for c in B)`, same thing for the `for` loop